# What is the maximum number of joins allowed in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

What is the maximum number of joins allowed in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no limit - it's only restricted by the server resources.

Comment: @Bridge - The duplicate is actually 2008 specific but AFAIK the answer for 2012 is essentially the same.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah - that's what I was thinking; it seems like there is no limit for versions after 2005.